# How to reduce objects in an array based off an existing key value

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

So I have an existing array with three objects:

```
              [ { date: 3/12/2022, oService: 10}
                { date: 3/13/2022, oService: 12, aService: 1}
                { date: 3/13/2022, oService: 1 }]
```

Based on the date, I would like to get something that looks like the following:

```
                [ {date: 3/12/2022, oService: 10}
                  {date: 3/13/2022, oService: 13, aService: 1}]
```

additionally, I could have up to 10 services, so I cant reduce by prev.oService. I'll have an array of services that looks something like:

`const Services = [aService, bService, cService, oService, yService]`

Comment: What about Array.prototype.filter() (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)?

Comment: I tried that, but Im not sure how i would compare the previous dates with filter.

Comment: I understand that you only want those entries in the array with a specific date? Then filter is the way to go.

Comment: So I want that if the entries share a date, and then they have matching services on those dates, to add those services values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most efficient method to groupby on an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: @Dani thats exactly what I have in the clipboard right now :)

Comment: its actually close, but still doesnt solve my question :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's best to think of the problem as 2 different steps:

- First, get all things that belong to the same date together. This is a `groupBy` that you should be able to look up on StackOverflow or borrow from an existing library.
- Then, you *merge* each of the date groups in to a single object.

The `merge` operation is a bit more custom than the `groupBy` operation. You can implement it in many ways. I would propose to:

- Implement `merge` to deal with just `2` objects
- Inside `merge`, loop over all unique keys in those objects and sum them (excluding the `date` key)
- To apply `merge` to a date group, use `reduce`. Note that it's safe to not provide a seed argument here, because you are guaranteed to not have empty groups.

```js
// Merge two date-service entries in to one
const merge = (a, b) => {
  const merged = Object.assign({}, a);
  
  Object.keys(b).forEach(k => {
    if (k !== "date")
      merged[k] = (merged[k] || 0) + b[k];
  });
  
  return merged;
};

const input = [ { date: "3/12/2022", oService: 10},
                { date: "3/13/2022", oService: 12, aService: 1},
                { date: "3/13/2022", oService: 1 }];
          
// Create groups that have a matching date
const byDate = groupByProp("date", input);

// Reduce each group to a single item by merging
const all = Object.values(byDate).map(xs => xs.reduce(merge));

console.log(all);

// A basic `groupBy` implementation
function groupByProp(prop, xs) { 
  return xs.reduce(
    (groups, x) => {
      const k = x[prop];
      if (!groups[k]) groups[k] = [x];
      else groups[k].push(x);
      return groups;
    },
    {}
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you so much. This is the right solution.